# Existence of a countable locally finite cover with nonempty intersection of two adjacent elements

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let $\Omega$ be an open connected set in $\mathbb{C}$, not necessarily bounded. Does there exist a countable locally finite cover of $\Omega$ consisting of only open discs  $\{ B(z_i, r_i): i\geq 1\}$ satisfying the following properties:

$(i)$ $\overline{B(z_i, r_i)}\subset \Omega$.

$(ii)$ $B(z_i, r_i) \cap B(z_{i+1}, r_{i+1})\neq \emptyset$ for all $i\geq 1$?

This statement is used in a theorem that states that the second de Rham cohomology group of such an $\Omega$ is $\{0\}$.

It will be great (sufficient as well) if anyone can give me a proof (or source) of the latter statement in terms of the differential forms involving only $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider an annulus, which is open and connected in $\Bbb C$ and homotopic to the circle $S^1$. As such the first de Rham cohomology is $\cong \Bbb R$, and not $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I asked for "second" de Rham cohomology group.

Comment: I believe the annulus will give you a counter example to the existence of such a covering. Specifically condition (ii) will give you a continuous path from the centers of the balls, together with local finiteness and condition (i) it should follow that you approach any point on the boundary arbitrarily closely with this path. For the annulus you will then find a limit point of the path (ie a point to which the path returns arbitrarily close infinitely often) in the interior, this will contradict the local finiteness of the covering.

Comment: Okay, my question is partially answered in Lee's Smooth Manifold (Theorem 17.32). I am still trying to figure it out. He did not say anything about open discs, but it is close to the statement that I wrote. You can also find it in Spivak's Differential Geometry (Vol 1), problem number 20, chapter 8.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{ B_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a locally finite covering of $\Omega$ by open connected sets (they needn't be discs) satisfying conditions (i) and (ii). Let $K$ be a Jordan curve lying within $\Omega$ and let $C$ and $D$ be the two parts of $\Omega \setminus K$ lying inside and outside of $K$. $K$ is compact so  there is an $N$ such that $\bigcup_{n > N} B_n$ is disjoint from $K$. This union is connected (by condition (ii)) and so must lie within one of $C$ or $D$. If $D$ then $C$ is covered by $B_1, ...,B_N$ and, by (i), $\overline{C} \subset \Omega$, and vice versa. So one of $C$ or $D$ has no boundary points except in K, i.e. must be a whole component of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus K$. It follows that $\Omega$ is either the whole plane with at most one hole or is simply-connected. If the $B_n$s are bounded then it can only be simply connected.

If the $B_n$ are required to be disks then there is no such covering for an annulus even if condition (i) is dropped. Taking $K$ to be a concentric circle, one of the two components of the rest of the annulus would have to be covered by finitely many disks lying within the whole annulus. Given N such disks it will always be possible to find a concentric circle within the annulus but near enough to the boundary that less than $1/N$ of its circumference can be in any disk, and so it is not covered.